# How to search an array list query php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search

My code is as follows:

```
$query = "Select country, name, job
          from tab1.employee where name like ('%".$crit."%')";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<table BORDER=1 >';
    echo '<tr><th>Country</th><th>name</th><th>job</th></tr>';
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$r['country'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$r['name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$r['job'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

This is my code to search one "name" in the employee table. My issue is to find more than one string , i.e ('Peter', 'Gerard', 'Joseph'...).

The Html code side

```
<form method="POST" action="search.php" >
<input type="text" name="criterio">
<select name="dropdown">
<option value="Select">-- Select --</option>}
<option value="SKU-config">job</option>
<option value="UPC">name</option>
</select> 
<input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `IN` clause? *AFAIK* the `IN` clause doesn't work with the `LIKE` clause.

Comment: if that's your *real* code, you've a syntax error. Plus, you didn't "query". and where is `$result` coming from? Too many unknowns here.

Comment: `LIKE %something% OR LIKE %somethingelse% OR LIKE...`

Comment: Or better, use `REGEXP`, like this: `$conditions = implode("|", $crit); $query ="SELECT \`country\`, \`name\`, \`job\` FROM \`tab1\`.\`employee\` WHERE \`name\` REGEXP '{$conditions}'";`. Now execute your `$query`.

Comment: we also don't know what your db structure/schema/rows look like and how your data is in there. anyway, see the answers given below. I'll have to pass on this one.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I'd sure like to know how you were able to properly highlight those ticks `\`` lol I could never do it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just escaped the backticks using backslash(\\`). Don't worry, even I couldn't do it in the first few attempts. :)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul hehehe thanks. (done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that can help. One of them is:

```
$query = "SELECT country,name,job FROM tab1.employee WHERE name IN ('Peter','Gerard','Joseph')";
```

Another one is:

```
$query = "SELECT country,name,job FROM tab1.employee WHERE FIND_IN_SET(name, ('Peter','Gerard','Joseph'))";
```

The one I find best is this:

```
$query = "SELECT country,name,job FROM tab1.employee WHERE name REGEXP ('Peter','Gerard','Joseph')";
```

I hope you find what you need in this!

Comment: I tend to think that one or all of those should work for the OP. However, and given no comment from them nor a green tick next to your answer, either means they've taken off and won't get back till suppertime, or that it didn't solve it for them. I'm pulling towards the fact that it's the way they're storing their data and I for one, wouldn't have put in an answer for this one. Too many unknowns. I hope you haven't fallen into a rabbit hole ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Who knows. But thank you for the concern. I love you too Fred haha :P

Comment: @Chris it help a little bit, but the idea is to write in a box a list of names and then run the query in the backend . What can I do changing the names peter.... by a variable that receive the value of the textbox.

Comment: Can you give some more code or something so I can have a better idea what you need? It is a bit unclear now...

Comment: I've added the html code side. the idea is to search a name or group of name from database and display it/them. it work for me when I search only one String, my blocker is when I want to search more than one string.

Comment: So you'll be using multiselect? Or can people just write names in the textbox? I'm not sure how you want to do this

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your query string. The below query string will give you all rows with the names Peter, Gerard and Joseph.

Using an IN statement would be the cleanest way to find multiple matches. Otherwise you'll end up with many "OR name LIKE " depending on how many names you want to match with.

```
$query = "
SELECT country,name,job
FROM tab1.employee 
WHERE name IN ('Peter','Gerard','Joseph')
";
```